# How to test boolean expressions in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, boolean, boolean-expression

I am trying to convert the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554014/how-to-examine-and-manipulate-iis-metadata-in-c to VBVcript.

My problem is with this code:

```
Function LocateVirtualDirectory(ByVal siteName, ByVal vdirName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim site
    For Each site in w3svc
        If (site.KeyType = "IIsWebServer") And (site.ServerComment = siteName) Then
            Set LocateVirtualDirectory = GetObject(site.Path & "/ROOT/" & vdirName)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

If `site.ServerComment` is `Empty`, then the whole boolean expression receives the value `Empty`, which is not False and hence the then-statement is entered.

What is the right way to write that expression? The shorter the better.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply nest the `If` statements, and insert an additional check to guard against the condition where `ServerComment` is `Empty`. I've also extracted the value of `site.ServerComment` into the temporary variable `comment` so that you won't be accessing the property twice.

For example:

```
Function LocateVirtualDirectory(ByVal siteName, ByVal vdirName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim site
    Dim comment
    For Each site in w3svc
        If site.KeyType = "IIsWebServer" Then
            comment = site.ServerComment
            If (comment <> Empty) And (comment = siteName) Then
                Set LocateVirtualDirectory = GetObject(site.Path & "/ROOT/" & vdirName)
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Another benefit of nesting the `If` statements is to short-circuit the evaluation. VBScript (and VB 6) don't short-circuit conditional evaluations—the `And` operator works as a logical one, requiring that both sides of the conditional are tested in order for a result to be determined. Because there's no reason to check the `ServerComment` if the `KeyType` doesn't match, you'll gain a little in performance by short-circuiting the expression. The only way to achieve that in VBScript is nesting (there is no `AndAlso`).

I should also point out that there is absolutely no point to testing if a value `= True`. You can simply rewrite `(site.ServerComment = siteName) = True` as `site.ServerComment = siteName`, and achieve exactly the same result. It took me at least several minutes to figure out what your original code even did because that's such an unnatural way of writing conditionals.

Comment: I'd recommend `If Not IsEmpty(site.ServerComment) And ...`, but anyway… Comparing an `Empty` variable to a string yields `False` for me, not `Empty`. Comparing `Empty` to `Empty` yields `False` as well.

Comment: Strange, I was trying to use IsEmpty but it did not work. I guess I have confused something.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing as Tomalak. I had a hard time imagining the behavior you were describing, but Variants have always been a major pain. When I wrote my answer, I was on a Mac and didn't have VBScript handy for testing purposes. Either way, I'm glad to see that you're on the right track now.